# Is it dumb to make a dynamic 2d array where the second dimension is a constant?

Tags: c++

I am trying to make an array with a variable number of rows, but it will always have 4 columns.  Is doing something like:

```
int** numGrades = new int* [num_exams];
for (int i = 0; i < num_exams; ++i)
{
    numGrades[i] = new int[4];
}
```

a good way to do this?  I feel like there's an easier way, but I can't think of one.  Also, the array keeps giving me memory leaks so I'm wondering if that is because I'm doing something I shouldn't be.  Vectors are banned for this program fyi.

Comment: What will you use it for?

Comment: It's part of a bigger assignment where I am calculating student grades.  This particular array would store a the number of each grade (A, B, C, D, F) on each exam for any given number of exams.

Comment: Answer - NO. If you are dealing with something that always has 4 `int`, though, your allocation should be `int (*numGrades)[4] = new int[num_exams][4];` to provide for a *single-allocation* and *single-free* of the block of memory (makes reallocating much easier too)

Comment: I tried allocating it like that, but now it won't let me pass the array to any of my functions.  It says "argument of type int* is incompatible with type int**".  Does declaring it the way you did make it no longer a 2d array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make an array of rows.

```
struct Row{
   int values[4];
};

Row* numGrades = new Row[num_exams];
```

Comment: Would there be any actual advantage to that?  I already have it as a 2d array, but if it's worth changing I will.

Comment: @aons32 Yes, it would reduce the need for dynamic allocations. You don't have to worry about `num_exams` allocations, but only about one.  If vectors are not allowed this would probably be the best solution.

Comment: That would probably fix the weird memory leaks too.  I'll probably give that a try tomorrow.

Comment: Alternatives: `new std::array<int,4>[num_exams];` if not all STL containers are banned, or even `new int[4 * num_exams];`.

Comment: @aons32 Another advantage of the struct approach: If each row represents the exams for one student, then you can also add functions to the struct and do stuff like this: `for (const Row& student : numGrades) student.calculateAverage();`, or, as David C. Rankin suggested, overload operator >> and << for reading and writing student data.

Comment: @churill I tried the array of rows, but now the program aborts when I do: `delete[] numGrades` and I can't figure out why.

Comment: @aons32 Please ask a new question then. The comment section is not made to for further discussions :)

Answer (score 0):

You could skip the for loop:

```
int* numGrades = new int[num_exams*4];
int firstElement = numGrades[x];
int secondElement = numGrades[x+1];
int thirdElement = numGrades[x+2];
int fourthElement = numGrades[x+3];
```

By skipping the for loop you gain this:

1. You don't have to have a for-loop for freeing the memory:

   delete[] numGrades;
2. The heap does not fragment so much because you don't call "new" so many times.

BUT it all depends what you are using it for. In modern C++ is not such a good idea to use dynamic but make a struct in a std::vector.

Comment: I would rather use vectors but I'm not allowed to.  And what would the point of skipping the for loop be?

Comment: @aons32 I added an explanation why skipping the for loop is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this.

```
typedef int row[4];
//or
using row = int[4];

row *numGrades = new row[num_exams];
```

Answer (score 0):

Allocating some number of arrays of fixed size is fine and advantageous in many cases.

In addition to a `struct` (which is a very good option), another option is to declare a *Pointer-To-Array* of a fixed number of elements. The benefit there is you have a *Single-Allocation* and *Single-Free* for the block of memory. (as you do with an *array of struct*) If you need to grow the block of memory (with a -- declare bigger block, copy existing to bigger, delete existing reallocation), it simplifies the process. In your case:

```
 int (*numGrades)[4] = new int[num_exams][4];
```

Which will allocate `num_exams` number of arrays of 4 `int` all at once. That provides the benefit of a single `delete[] numGrades;` when  you are done with the memory.

A short example that uses a `std::istringstream` to hold example values to be read into a block of memory containing fixes size arrays could be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main (void) {
    
    std::istringstream iss { "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9" };
    
    int npoints = 3,
        (*points)[3] = new int[npoints][3],
        n = 0;
    
    while (n < 3 && iss >> points[n][0] >> points[n][1] >> points[n][2])
        n++;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        std::cout << points[i][0] << "  " << points[i][1] << "  " << points[i][2] << '\n';
    
    delete[] points;
}
```

(**note:** you should avoid using `new` and `delete` in favor of a container such as [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) if this is for other than educational purposes)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/newptr2array3
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

Worth noting, the benefit of the `struct` is that it will allow you to overload `>>` and `<<` with `std::istream` and `std::ostream` to provide a convenient functions to read and write the data you need.

So either way, a *Pointer-to-Array* of fixed elements, or creating a `struct` and then an *Array of `struct`* is perfectly fine.